# MySQL nesting optimization

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to solve this for 2 hours now, and can't success

Attached below is the response for this query:

```
SELECT login, SUM(gain) AS weekly_gain
FROM gt_history
WHERE is_closed = 1 AND (cmd = 0 OR cmd = 1)
GROUP BY WEEK(close_time), login
```

Now, what i would like to do is, to make an `AVERAGE` of all the values, `GROUP BY` login.

Ideas?

[image: result from first query]

Comment: why sum when you need average?

Comment: i need to sum for the days of every week, and then make a weekly average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use query You have as sub-query.

```
SELECT login, AVG(weekly_gain) FROM
    (SELECT login, SUM(gain) AS weekly_gain
    FROM gt_history
    WHERE is_closed = 1 AND (cmd = 0 OR cmd = 1)
    GROUP BY WEEK(close_time), login)
GROUP BY login
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  login,
  AVG(weekly_gain) AS weekly_gain
FROM (SELECT
    login,
    SUM(gain) AS weekly_gain
      FROM gt_history
      WHERE is_closed = 1
      AND (cmd = 0
        OR cmd = 1)
      GROUP BY WEEK(close_time), login) As l
```

Comment: no :( your query returns the general average and not the average of the weekly sum :)